# Unity-Issue with spawning enemies after first wave is defeated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity project that has three different types of enemies. Right now, I have it that when the game starts one of each of the three enemies will come out. So far, so good. The issue is that when I kill one of the enemies I want the enemies from that type to spawn over and over again. So basically, game starts with one of each enemy with NO other enemies coming out. When I kill one of the types, that type comes out over and over again until they probably kill me. Here is my code:

```
    public bool waveOne = true;
    public float subTime = .5f; //Lab 11 work

    #endregion Member Variables

    #region Member Functions

    void Start ()
    {
    if (waveOne == true) {
            Invoke ("Spawn", spawnTime);
        } 
        else {
            // Call the Spawn function after a delay of the spawnTime and then continue to call after the same amount of time.
            InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
        }
    }
```

The above function is what spawns one of each type.

I tried creating this function to call repeating enemies:

```
    public void callEnemies()
    {
        waveOne = false;
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);

    }
```

I would call callEnemies in my enemyHealth.cs under my death function.

```
        public void Death ()
    {
        // The enemy is dead.
        isDead = true;

        // Turn the collider into a trigger so shots can pass through it.
        capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;
        EnemyManager.Instance.callEnemies();

        // Tell the animator that the enemy is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");

        // Change the audio clip of the audio source to the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt clip playing).
        enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
        enemyAudio.Play ();


        #region Lab10 Addition

        // Kill the Enemy (remove from EnemyList)
        // Get the game object associated with "this" EneymHealth script
        // Then get the InstanceID of that game object.
        // That is the game object that needs to be killed.
        EnemyManager.Instance.Kill(this.gameObject.GetInstanceID());

        #endregion // Lab10 Addition

    }
```

So right now, only one of my three enemies comes pouring out. But the other two do not. Any help would be great!

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Member Variables

```
    #region LAB10 Addition

    public static EnemyManager Instance
    {
        get { return EnemyManager._Instance; }
    }
    private static EnemyManager _Instance = null;

    public EnemyManager()
    {
        if (EnemyManager._Instance == null) EnemyManager._Instance = this;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, Object> EnemyList = new Dictionary<int, Object>();

    #endregion // LAB10 Addition


    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;       // Reference to the player's heatlh.
    public GameObject enemy;                // The enemy prefab to be spawned.
    public float spawnTime = 3f;            // How long between each spawn.
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;         // An array of the spawn points this enemy can spawn from.
    public bool waveOne = true;
    public float subTime = .5f; //Lab 11 work

    #endregion Member Variables

    #region Member Functions

    void Start ()
    {
    if (waveOne == true) {
            Invoke ("Spawn", spawnTime);
        } 
        else {
            // Call the Spawn function after a delay of the spawnTime and then continue to call after the same amount of time.
            InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
        }
    }


    void Spawn ()
    {
        // If the player has no health left...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f)
        {
            // ... exit the function.
            return;
        }

        // Find a random index between zero and one less than the number of spawn points.
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

        #region LAB10 Addition

        // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position and rotation.
        // Original Code (next line) did not capture the resulting object.
        // Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
        Object o = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
        EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList.Add(o.GetInstanceID(), o);

        #endregion // LAB10 Addition

    #region Lab 11

    ((GameObject)o).GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().EnemyHealthHandler += ScoreManager.EnemyHealthEvent;


    #endregion

    }

    #region Lab10 Addition

    public void Kill(int InstanceID)
    {
        if (EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList.ContainsKey(InstanceID))
            EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList.Remove(InstanceID);

    //Lab 11 notes
    //bool IsAlive = (playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f) ? true : false;

    }

    public void DeathToAll()
    {
        Dictionary<int, Object> TempEnemyList = new Dictionary<int, Object>(EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Object> kvp in TempEnemyList)
        {
            // kvp.Key;   // = InstanceID
            // kvp.Value; // = GameObject

            GameObject go = (GameObject)kvp.Value;
            go.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().Death();
        }

    }

    #endregion // Lab10 Addition

    public void callEnemies()
    {
        waveOne = false;
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);

    }

    #endregion Member Functions
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code that actually spawns the enemies?

Comment: @Abion47-I have included the full code in the most recent edit.

Comment: When you spawn an enemy, you are spawning an instance of the prefab within the `enemy` object, but I don't see anywhere in your code that reassigns `enemy` to anything else. That's why you are only spawning one type of enemy, because you aren't telling your game to spawn anything else.

Comment: do you know how to fix that? I am just starting out with Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your intention correctly, your pitfall is in your "Spawn" method

```
void Spawn ()
    {
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f)
        {
            return;
        }
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);
        Object o = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation); // only one
        EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList.Add(o.GetInstanceID(), o);
       ((GameObject)o).GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().EnemyHealthHandler += ScoreManager.EnemyHealthEvent;
    }
```

You are instantiating only one enemy off of a prefab loaded into one gameobject. We don't have enough of your code to write a complete solution, but it seems you'd want to instantiate all three and keep track of which type is killed to spawn more of that type.

EDIT:
After reading your comment I recognized why it gets stuck on one enemy.
Look at the singleton:

```
public static EnemyManager Instance
    {
        get { return EnemyManager._Instance; }
    }
    private static EnemyManager _Instance = null;

    public EnemyManager()
    {
        if (EnemyManager._Instance == null) EnemyManager._Instance = this;
    }
```

When you create the first enemy, the _instance is getting set to "this". When you try to make the second enemy, the if statement is false and the type of enemy remains the first one.

The static _instance is the same for all instances of the script.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, in unity we are attaching the script to all three of them enemies. So it is basically one 'script' per enemy. Not sure if that helps but thank you  for that.

Comment: @MikeCuddy You shouldn't have the spawning behavior handled entirely by the different enemy types, since they would have no way to communicate with each other and decide which of them should spawn next. You should have a SpawnManager script that handles the spawning independently.

Comment: @MikeCuddy True. I refined my answer. Abion47's approach hints at the right design pattern.

Comment: For a Singleton pattern, it's better to instantiate the singleton in a static constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will be working with this and seeing what I can find out!